# Dynamic representation of a plot using streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit, cryptofeed

I'm implementing a simple visualizer of a xy plot using streamlit (just a point for testing).

The idea is to get the data via a library called cryptofeed and plot it dynamically using streamlit.
Everytime the function "book" is called, we should represent a point in a xy graph. However, it returns the following error: *raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'*

Do you know how to solve it?

The code is the following:

```
import streamlit as st
from cryptofeed import FeedHandler
from cryptofeed.defines import L2_BOOK
from cryptofeed.exchanges.kraken_futures import KrakenFutures
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

async def book(book, receipt_timestamp):
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1], [float(book.book.asks.index(0)[0])]]).T
    df.columns = ['a', 'b']
    c = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(x='a', y='b', tooltip=['a', 'b'])
    chart_row.altair_chart(c, use_container_width=True)

def main():
    config = {'log': {'filename': 'demo.log', 'level': 'INFO'}}
    f = FeedHandler(config=config)

    Symbols = ['BTC-USD-PERP', 'BTC-USD-21Z31', 'BTC-USD-22H25', 'BTC-USD-22M24']

    f.add_feed(KrakenFutures(symbols=Symbols, channels=[L2_BOOK],
                             callbacks={L2_BOOK: book}))

    f.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chart_row = st.empty()
    st.write("Here's our first attempt at using data to create a table:")
    main()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `async` may need to run `async event loop` which can run many `async functions` at the same time. And this `event loop` has to run in one thread - if you try to use `async function` in another thread then it can't find `event loop`. But `FeedHandler` may run code in separated thread and it may try to execute `book` also in separated thread and it can make problem. Using `async` and threads at the same time sometimes can make big problems - they are not created to work each other.

Comment: After spending one entire day trying to solve this problem, I conclude that it is almost impossible to get a simple solution. This problem is all over the internet (https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/real-time-data-streaming-and-plot-updating/7337) and I couldn't get any reasonable solution.

Comment: the only idea - run `FeedHandler` in separated thread and put values in `Queue`. And main thread with `streamlit` whould have to run periodically code which would get data from `Queue` and update plot. Problem is that I don't see in `streamlit` function to run some code periodically. Using `Dash` instead of `streamlit` you could use `dcc.Interval` for this.